# How to define a max limit of options in react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I created a react select component for my app react and I have more than 70 options, for that I want to define a max limit of options that the user can choose to handle it well. Can you please help me?

The code:

```
export default function ReactSelect(props) {
  const animatedComponents = makeAnimated();
  return (
    <Select
      isMulti="true" // allow to select mutli options
      isRtl="true" // right to left
      name="name" // html name
      options={accountsNames} // options
      className="basic-multi-select"
      classNamePrefix="select"
      isSearchable="true" // searchable for the closest one
      placeholder="اختر اسم الحساب..." // if there is no option selected
      components={animatedComponents}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Saw multiple answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55119120/how-to-set-max-number-of-items-that-can-be-selected-in-react-select) that might help you too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can control the selected options state and disable the options conditionally based on `selectedOptions.length` like this:

```
const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = React.useState([]);

return (
  <Select
    isMulti
    value={selectedOptions}
    onChange={(o) => setSelectedOptions(o)}
    options={colourOptions}
    // only allow user to choose up to 3 options
    isOptionDisabled={() => selectedOptions.length >= 3}
    className="basic-multi-select"
    classNamePrefix="select"
  />
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thank you so much, If I may ask, I like in your demo the option went gray that look like disabled, how can I do the same?

Comment: @Drsaud I just forked the codesandbox from the official docs [here](https://react-select.com/home#:~:text=RTL-,Multi,-import%20React%20from), I think it's the default style of `react-select` (didn't change anything).

Comment: Don't forget to add the `option.isDisabled` check again, as your example breaks the default API now. Something like `isOptionDisabled={option => option.isDisabled || selectedOptions.length >= 3}`

Answer (score 3):

This might help:

```
const MultiSelect = ({valueList, onChange, options, maxLimit = 5}) => {
  return (
    <Select
      value={valueList}
      isMulti
      onChange={onChange}
      options={options}
      isOptionDisabled={(option) => valueList.length >= maxLimit}
    />
  );
};
```